# Identifying mutations between two sequences

Tags: r, bioinformatics, string-comparison, bioconductor

Given two sequences (such as DNA sequences) of equal length, I want to be able to find the mutations between them - both type and index within the sequence. As an example, if I fed in the sequences `AGGCTAC` and `AGCCTTC`, I want to get out a list like `G3C, A6T`.

I can get the *number* of differences just fine:

```
seqs <- Biostrings::readAAStringSet("PSE-1_Round20.fas")
nmut <- adist(seqs[1], seqs)
```

But I can't think of a more elegant way to get the positions than just looping, which seems very kludgy - and I'd like to take this as an opportunity to learn instead.

I'm working with the `Biostrings` package in R, but there don't seem to be any special tools in that package for what I want to do any I think any solution that works for generic strings should also work for me. In fact, if there's a more elegant solution in python or bash scripting, I'd also accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be multiple packages that should do this. One is the `findMutations` function in the `adegenet` package.

As for the string comparison question, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821084/how-to-compare-characters-of-two-string-at-each-index). Here's a function that will work if the strings are the same length:

```
mutations <- function(str1, str2) {
  str1vec <- unlist(strsplit(str1, ""))
  str2vec <- unlist(strsplit(str2, ""))
  iMut <- (1:length(str1vec))[str1vec != str2vec]
  return(paste0(str1vec[iMut], iMut, str2vec[iMut]))
}

> mutations("AGGCTAC", "AGCCTTC")
[1] "G3C" "A6T"
```